# Underlying Connection Failed after some time

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2012

We have a `WPF application` which communicates through `REST API` hosted on Production Environment running `SQL Server 2012`.
WPF application works fine but after some few hours of CRUD operations it keeps throwing `Under Lying Connection Close exception.` Until I restart the `SQL Services` I am running `SQL Express Edition 2012` also on development environment. But it works fine on development environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons this could occurr 1) Server or router has settings that are closing the TCP connection.  Like a maximum open time. 2) More often this occurs due to the tables that TCP keeps for retrying packets.  TCP breaks messages into 1500 byte datagrams (data portion of packet).  TCP sends an ACK for each messages sent. When a packet doesn't get ACK it will get resent usually 3-5 times at around 5 seconds a retry. Packets also can be receive in random order.  So the sending side of TCP must keep each packet in a table until an ACK is received.  Then remove packet from table.  The receiver must have table to reorder packets.  Packets are removed from table when all previous packets are received.  These tables can get very large and then the operating system will probably close application.  Normally what causes this to happen is when the receiving end is running a lot of applications it doesn't ACK a message in 5 seconds.  So the Sending end re-sends packets.  The resend packets sends more data which adds more processing to the receiver slowing the receiver even more.  The best way of checking for issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if you see duplicate packet numbers which indicates a retry.  You should normally see each packet number twice (once when sent and once when ACK).